# Why do my Hyper-V networks get an IP on my Host Server?

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I set up a new Hyper-V Host Server. I run two VMs on this Server, each of them with their own Virtual Network, which is a NIC Team. Here are the teams:

```
[HVHost]: PS C:\Users\xy\Documents> Get-NetLbfoTeam


Name                   : Hyper-V Team 1
Members                : {Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 1, Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 3}
TeamNics               : Hyper-V Team 1
TeamingMode            : SwitchIndependent
LoadBalancingAlgorithm : HyperVPort
Status                 : Degraded

Name                   : Local
Members                : {Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 4, Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 2}
TeamNics               : Local
TeamingMode            : SwitchIndependent
LoadBalancingAlgorithm : Dynamic
Status                 : Up

Name                   : Hyper-V Team 2
Members                : {PCIe Slot 1 Port 3, PCIe Slot 1 Port 2, PCIe Slot 1 Port 1, PCIe Slot 1 Port 4}
TeamNics               : Hyper-V Team 2
TeamingMode            : SwitchIndependent
LoadBalancingAlgorithm : HyperVPort
Status                 : Degraded
```

Now when I run `ipconfig` on the Host Server I expect to only get my `Local` network team returned, however I get this:

```
[HVHost]: PS C:\Users\xy\Documents> ipconfig

Windows-IP-Konfiguration


Ethernet-Adapter Local:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: internal.domain.com
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::d4f:84c6:586e:1799%12
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.102
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.215

Ethernet-Adapter vEthernet (HVE_X):

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: internal.domain.com
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::71d4:82d1:6c1a:d454%30
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.141
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.215

Ethernet-Adapter vEthernet (HVE_Y):

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: internal.domain.com
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::d94e:fa85:1007:e320%36
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.133
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.215
```

Why do I get the two `vEthernet` NICs returned? How can I hide them?

I have a similar Server that also has 3 NIC Teams, 2 for Hyper-V and one for local, and when i do a `ipconfig` there, I only get the local stuff returned:

```
[SimilarHVHost]: PS C:\Users\xy\Documents> ipconfig

Windows-IP-Konfiguration


Ethernet-Adapter Lokal:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.243
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.215

Tunneladapter isatap.{084F9961-69B0-4F13-9D4D-B4F48F2EEE56}:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
```

What setting am I missing on my new Hyper-V Host Server? I would like it to behave like the other Hyper-V Host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties of the virtual switch, uncheck the box labeled "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter".

[image]